# jQuery - moving elements with appendTo not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move some h3 tags from top div to bottom div and **the opposite** via click event.
Everything works just fine until I click on a recently moved element to see the opposite action.

For example, I click on **Item 1**. it goes to bottom div. Again click on Item 1, it doesn't work. Why?

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("div#top h3").click(function(e) {
    $(e.target.tagName + "#" + e.target.id).detach().appendTo("div#down");
  });
  $("div#down h3").click(function(e) {
    $(e.target.tagName + "#" + e.target.id).detach().appendTo("div#top");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">
  <h1>Top</h1>
  <h3 id="th3-1">Item 1</h3>
  <h3 id="th3-2">Item 2</h3>
  <h3 id="th3-3">Item 3</h3>
</div>

<div id="down">
  <h1>Down</h1>
  <h3 id="dh3-1">Item 4</h3>
  <h3 id="dh3-2">Item 5</h3>
  <h3 id="dh3-3">Item 6</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code applies the `click` function to the *current* set of matched elements (on document ready). Clicking an element in `#top` works because it had the event listener attached. It's then moved to `#down`, but the click function remains - it will be re-appended to `#down` on subsequent clicks. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st8rvku2/), click items 1 then 2 in Top. They will be moved to Down. Then click item 1 and see that it is appended to the end of Down. Click item 2 again, and see the same. Event delegation with `.on()` allows you to use "live" selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to have dynamic behavior based on the location of the element, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#top").on('click', 'h3', function (e) {
        $(this).appendTo("#down");
    });
    $("#down").on('click', 'h3', function (e) {
        $(this).appendTo("#top");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/38Lepzb9/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it to determine where the H3 is onclick and move accordingly.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
 $("div > h3").click(function(e){
  if($(this).parent().attr('id') == 'top')
   $(e.target.tagName+"#"+e.target.id).detach().appendTo("div#down");
  else
   $(e.target.tagName+"#"+e.target.id).detach().appendTo("div#top");
 });
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ct67ef7/2/).

Comment: While this does work, it's an indirect solution at best. Look at ArunPJohny's answer and [`.on()` with event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)